# Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: livePerson in Casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, automated-tests, casperjs

I am trying to write **Automated Journey Tests using CasperJs and PhantomJs:**

My Package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "casperjsdemo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "JourneyTest.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha-casperjs/bin/mocha-casperjs JourneyTest.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha-casperjs": "~0.3.2",
    "casperjs": "^1.1.3",
    "phantomjs": "^2.1.7"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com"
}
```

I am trying to execute Test using following command:

```
node_modules/casperjs/bin/casperjs test <JourneyTestFile>.js
```

However :( I am getting following Error :

```
Error: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: livePerson
```

For Reference My Journey Test File is as Below:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1366, height: 517};
casper.on('page.error', function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo('Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR');
    for(var i=0; i<trace.length; i++) {
        var step = trace[i];
        this.echo('   ' + step.file + ' (line ' + step.line + ')', 'ERROR');
    }
});
casper.test.begin('Resurrectio test', function(test) {
    casper.start('https://www.example.com/');
    casper.waitForSelector("form[name=Login] input[name='username']",
        function success() {
            test.assertExists("form[name=Login] input[name='username']");
            this.click("form[name=Login] input[name='username']");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("form[name=Login] input[name='username']");
        });
    casper.waitForSelector("input[name='username']",
        function success() {
            this.sendKeys("input[name='username']", "akent86@bigpond.com");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("input[name='username']");
        });
    casper.waitForSelector("form[name=Login] input[name='password']",
        function success() {
            test.assertExists("form[name=Login] input[name='password']");
            this.click("form[name=Login] input[name='password']");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("form[name=Login] input[name='password']");
        });
    casper.waitForSelector("input[name='password']",
        function success() {
            this.sendKeys("input[name='password']", "Renae2809");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("input[name='password']");
        });
    casper.waitForSelector(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Log in']"),
        function success() {
            test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Log in']"));
            this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Log in']"));
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='Log in']"));
        });

    casper.run(function() {test.done();});
});
```

**strong text**